# "Restlessnessfullness" or "Restlessfullness" or combining words

Tags: word-formation

I was pondering over this for some time:

- We have a word "**restlessness**" which means "*impatience*" in most cases or sometimes "*fidgetiness*".
- We have a word "**fullness**" *(fulness)* which mostly means "*abundance*".

Can we combine these two words to mean "**abundance of impatience**" as follows:

- Restlessnessfullness
- Restlessfullness

Should we keep the full word or if there already is "**ness**" in both words, can we then omit it in the first word?

We have words like "**hopelessness**" and "**hopefullness**", "**rightfullness**", "**weightlessness**" so I was inspired by these kind of words.

According to grammar we should apply "**lessness**" or "**fullness**" to the original word. In my case "**rest**". But "**Rest**" and "**Restlessness**" are different words.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I guess I'm at a state of utter '_helplessness_'.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster: Restfulness](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/restfulness)

Comment: You can coin any word you like. Whether it will catch on or not is another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -less suffix means "lacking, not having" and the -ful suffix means "having (in abundance)".  The -ness suffix makes the quality into an abstract noun.

The anchor noun **rest**, is what is lacking or what is had in abundance.

Restless.

Restful.

We make those qualities into a noun:

Restless**ness**.

Restful**ness**

**Restless** "marked by absence of rest" -> impatient, fidgety.

**Restlessness** "the condition of absence of rest" -> impatience, fidgetyness.

**Restful** "having an abundance of rest" -> calm, sedate, tranquil.

**Restfulness** "the condition of abundance of rest" -> calmness, sedateness, tranquility.